# How can I speed up scraping dynamic pages with watir?

Tags: ruby, watir

I'm completely new to programming so bear with me. I want to scrape approximately 50,000 web pages with dynamic content. I've written a script in Ruby that lets me do this using Watir and Nokogiri but I need 7 seconds for the dynamic content to become visible. So if I were to scrape one page at a time I would need almost 100 hours.

Obviously I can run two or three separate scripts at the same time but is there a more efficient 'Ruby' way to do this? I'm working from a regular desktop with Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a method which downloads a page, for example:

```
def get_page
  url = "some url"
  page = Nokogiri.parse open url
  sleep 7 # wait for page to be ready
  # extract data here
end
```

Now you want to run that N times concurrently

```
3.times do
  Thread.new do
    get_page
  end
end
```

There are many nuances to threading but usage can also be this simple. You can have threads read/write from global variables i.e. if you have a variable with 1000 urls you have have a thread run `urls.pop` to get the next URL. Keep in mind that there may potentially be race conditions (i.e. two threads `pop` a url at the same time and get the same value). If this is a concern, see https://www.toptal.com/ruby/ruby-concurrency-and-parallelism-a-practical-primer for some advice on writing parallel (versus concurrent) code.